# PHP - how to include a php class file and execute a function

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, class

I'm trying to create a signature request for amazon's AWS api using PHP. I'm not too familiar with PHP so this question might seem extremely obvious, so for that I'm sorry -

Amazon provides sample code for generating the signature request to use their API - which can be found here:

http://aws.amazon.com/code/AWIS/402

Their instructions state simply:

```
Run php urlinfo.php ACCESS_KEY_ID SECRET_ACCESS_KEY site
```

But I'm not sure how to "run" a php file. My instinct was to include the php file so I could make a call to its public urlInfo function:

```
UrlInfo($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey, $site)
```

but if I include it:

```
<?php require_once ('urlinfo.php'); ?>
```

The page automatically generates the message:

```
Usage: ACCESS_KEY_ID SECRET_ACCESS_KEY site
```

So how do I call this php file from my index file and pass it the parameters it requires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The urlinfo.php script was intended to be ran via PHP command line interface and expects arguments passed on via cli.

If you remove the following portion of the code:

```
if (count($argv) < 4) {
    echo "Usage: $argv[0] ACCESS_KEY_ID SECRET_ACCESS_KEY site\n";
    exit(-1);
}
else {
    $accessKeyId = $argv[1];
    $secretAccessKey = $argv[2];
    $site = $argv[3];
}
```

And then do:

```
$accessKeyId = "youkeyid";
$secretAccessKey = "yoursecret"; 
$site = "yoursite";

include('urlinfo.php');
```

It will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following code at the bottom of the urlinfo.php file.

```
if (count($argv) < 4) {
    echo "Usage: $argv[0] ACCESS_KEY_ID SECRET_ACCESS_KEY site\n";
    exit(-1);
}
else {
    $accessKeyId = $argv[1];
    $secretAccessKey = $argv[2];
    $site = $argv[3];
}

$urlInfo = new UrlInfo($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey, $site);
$urlInfo->getUrlInfo();
```

Then you can use the following the code to generate the urlinfo you need.

```
$urlInfo = new UrlInfo($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey, $site);
$urlInfo->getUrlInfo();
```

Comment: So I guess I'm a little confused - wouldn't I need to run this every time I want to access the web service? What do I use as the "site" if I'm running this on localhost? Can I run it on localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have unix command line:

Type "which php" from the command line to see if your shell knows where your php bin file is.  If you get a path, type that path to run the file followed by the parameters ACCESS_KEY_ID SECRET_ACCESS_KEY site

Example:
/usr/local/bin/php urlinfo.php ACCESS_KEY_ID SECRET_ACCESS_KEY site

---

Answer (score 0):

The instructions to run the file mean you should type that command into a command prompt.

The sample code is meant as just that, a sample.  As such, they have tried to make it easy for you to run it without putting it into a web server.  Instead you can just execute php directly on it.

If you want to run it in a web server, you will need to rewrite the example to do so.